# I can't install package in vuejs

Tags: vue.js

[firebase error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aCFH.png)

[axios error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLbPX.png)

I can't install any package in my vue app

Comment: Please do not post your erros as images. Provide them as actual code.

Comment: whay ?? It's better to understand and show all detail

Comment: No, it´s not. It´s not possible to copy the text and you have to open multiple tabs to see everything at the same time. [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)